# Как переопределить контекстное меню на input-элементе?

Tags: javascript, html, события, contextmenu

Не работает переопределение контекстного меню инпутов.

В таблице внутри каждой `table-cell` находится `disabled` `input`-элемент (текст или чекбокс). На `table-row` блоке установлено событие `oncontextmenu`. В этом меню предполагается активировать инпуты для редактирования, сохранять и деактивировать. К сожалению меню переопределяется только если клик происходит по `table-cell` до начала инпута (в пределах `padding`), а если же кликнуть по инпуту, то установленный на нём `event.preventDefault()` не срабатывает, а появляется стандартное меню браузера для редактирования инпута.

Как это обойти? Хотелось бы, чтобы пользователь просто кликал по строке таблицы, которая подсветится при наведении, а не выискивал область где сработает кастомное меню.

Вот пример: на блоке работает, на инпуте нет.

```css
div {
    background: gray;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
Right click on input and div:<br>
<input type="text" value="input" disabled oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();alert(event.x)">
<hr>
<div oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();alert(event.x)">div</div>
```

[UPDATE]
Не работает на `disabled` инпуте. На активном работает

Comment: т.е. инпут должен находится внутри div?

Comment: @Evgenii да, это для редактирования базы админом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элементы с событием `disabled` игнорируют события возникшие на них. Но при этом могут передавать события вверх по дереву DOM (не во всех браузерах), поэтому обработчики событий могут быть размещены на родительских элементах. Вот, Firefox полностью. будет игнорировать все возникшие события и никуда не вздумает передавать их дальше.

При таком раскладе 2 варианта:

1. Создать невидимый элемент и поместить его перед заблоченным элементом. Событие возникнет не на кнопке, а на элементе перед ним и всплытием передаст общему родителю событие, где оно успешно обработается.
2. Стилями задать элементу видимость блокировка, а самому элементу задать `readonly` вместо `disabled`

1-ый вариант

```css
.row {
    background: gray;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.btn-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.4);
}
```

```html
Right click on input and div:<br>

<div class="row" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();alert(event.x)">
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <input type="text" value="input" disabled>
    <div class="btn-hidden" />
  </div>
</div>
```

2-ой вариант

```css
.row {
    background: gray;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3);
  color: rgb(84, 84, 84);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
Right click on input and div:<br>

<div class="row" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();alert(event.x)">
    <input class="btn" type="text" value="input" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался!
Получается на `disabled` элементах события мыши не работают, и при этом не переходят к родителю. А если прописать в стилях `input[disabled] { pointer-events: none; }`, то событие дойдёт до родительского элемента, где оно может быть переопределено, и всё будет работать.

Comment: Этот вариант тоже хорош))